# prestashop back office custom module template for listing OR override by module

Tags: templates, module, admin, prestashop

due to ps documentation is rather bare, 'd like to know if anybody solve the probelm at subj.

have the last stable ps. 1.6.1.7 done many modules ...

needs help for (custom table [created]: OK, custom listing [ordering, filtering]: OK): when i click on a row (subq: when add an "addRowAction()" produce the same ...), want to see another controllers edit/update page - escpecially: controller = adminproduct & updateproduct ... the id_product is given, but also dunno how to pass:.

Specially: listing of ordered products (own modul, own list) want to ovveride the link it's automatically provide. I'm sure this is very simple, but nowhere found solution yet ...

the most question is: how to override (must to copy into my module structure?) a list helper, any other helpers ... or need to write a full .tpl to got function(s) above ...

Comment: Please be more clear about the problem, what do you want and how you have tried to solve it.

Comment: problem is not clear, please be specific and show us some code that you have tried or some screens to understand

Comment: The question is general ... how to override a helper?

when you list a database in BO, you got a default "pointer-class" link for rows, links to your own module's "edit/modify" method ...

i want to override this behavour to point another controller's "modify" method (ie.: products -> modify) ..

Comment: and sorry, if my En. or question is not clear .... but pushing negatives .... let me not to say anything to negative voters :P

Comment: ... and of course, finally i can solve my problem with implementing own "modify" method and redirecting to needed place... but i think this is not the most nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, implemented the ugly solution for my q. ( with codes :) ):

> part of _construct()...:

```
    $this->fields_list = array();
    $this->fields_list['id_order'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Order ID'),
        'align' => 'center',
        'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
        'type' => 'int'
    );
    $this->fields_list['product_reference'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Product reference'),
        'filter_key' => 'product_reference',
    );
    $this->fields_list['product_name'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Name'),
        'filter_key' => 'product_name'
    );
    $this->fields_list['product_quantity'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Pices'),
        'filter_key' => 'product_quantity'
    );
    $this->fields_list['total_price_tax_incl'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Full price incl. tax.'),
        'filter_key' => 'total_price_tax_incl',
        'type' => 'int'
    );

    $this->_join .= ' LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` b ON ( a.`id_order` = b.`id_order` )';
    $this->_select .= ' b.`date_add`,';
    $this->fields_list['date_add'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Added'),
        'filter_key' => 'b!date_add',
    );

    $this->_join .= ' LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'vatera_kl_order` c ON (c.`id_order` = b.`id_order` )';
    $this->_select .= ' c.`status` AS vstatus, ';
    $this->fields_list['vstatus'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Vatera status'),
        'filter_key' => 'c!status'
    );

    $this->_group .= 'GROUP BY `id_order`';

    $this->_orderBy = 'id_order';
    $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';

    parent::__construct();//ddd($this);
```

> one private function, to get id_product (product_id in order_details), and an overrided initContent() to do the ugly redirect ...:

```
private function getPidFromODID($odid) {
    $q = 'SELECT `product_id` FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_detail` WHERE `id_order_detail` = ' . $odid;
    $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS(
        $q
        );
    return $result[0]['product_id'];
}

public function initContent()
{
    if ($this->display == 'edit') {
        $admin = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,_PS_ADMIN_DIR_);
        $admin_folder = array_pop((array_slice($admin, -1)));
        Tools::redirect(
            _PS_BASE_URL_ . '/' . $admin_folder . '/' . $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminProducts') . '&id_product=' . (int)$this->getPidFromODID(Tools::getValue('id_order_detail')) . '&updateproduct');
    }
    else
        parent::initContent();
}
```

So, the original question is till question ... a nice method, to override the list behaviour ...